# How to make this cool navigation menu

Tags: css, navigation

I was surfing on the internet and I found a cool navigation that I want to use on my own website. But I really don't know how I can make it. Here is the link: http://www.welikesmall.com Does someone have a tutorial or someone that want to help me?

Already thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a place to have people write code for you. I just looked at the site, all the source is readable and formatted very nicely. I would recommend learning the basics of CSS and javascript to get a better idea of how to do what it is you want.

Comment: I'm only a bit new with css-animations, but maybe there is a tutorial of how this is made?